# Keras exception: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow, machine-learning-model, numpy

I have an understanding of this error, it means that the input that I'm passing to the model is of a different dimension that what was expected. The error also states that the input that I'm passing is of the dimension (1,) while it was expecting (2,)

I have tested the input value dimension by using x.shape and it prints out (2,) still the error exists. As a counter-intuitive move I picked one of the data that was in the training data and printed the shape of the zeroth element x1[0].shape also used that as an input, the error still exists.

model.fit works well, having error with model.predict (tried passing one of the training data hardcoded, still doesn't work)

*CODE:*

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
import csv

x1, ys = [], []

with open('./house.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line > 0:
            x1.append([row[1], row[3]])
            ys.append(row[5])
        line += 1


model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[2])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
x1 = np.asarray(x1, dtype=float)
ys = np.asarray(ys, dtype=float)
model.fit(x1, ys, epochs=500)

print(x1[0].shape)
while True:
    house_size = float(input('Enter the house size: '))
    house_size = house_size/3000
    bhks = float(input('Enter the BHK: '))
    bhks = bhks/3
    x = np.array([house_size, bhks])
    try:
        value = model.predict(x)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(x)
        print(x.shape)
    else:
        value = value[0][0] * 500
        print(value)
```

Comment: Can we get some sample data of your houses.csv file so we know what input_size you are trying to use?

Comment: Input size is 2. I'm passing house_size and bhk as two factors of X  [house_size, bhk] against the Y (house_rate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy always need to pass the data for prediction in batches, although this batch is of size one (one sample). Try changing this line:

```
x = np.array([house_size, bhks])
```

into this:

```
x = np.array([[house_size, bhks]])
```

This should work.

Comment: I also had a doubt, can't we pass multiple X values? Like, model.fit([x1, x2], ys, epochs=500) ?